# how to filter iframe tag using python beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python, iframe, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.@@@@@@.com/@@/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    if link['href'].startswith('http://'):
        print(link)
```

I am using these code, through that script parsing the href tag but when trying with iframe they can't give the output. I dont know what happening there. anyone suggest me plz...

Comment: Are you trying to get links inside an iframe which is part of `page`? Then I believe you have to download iframe's content separately.

Comment: helo Anton sir, am done only just href replace and add iframe tag

Answer (score 1):

how about use iframe and src and also like requests it is better them   urllib2

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import urllib2
import requests
#page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.@@@@@@.com/@@/")
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'}
page1 = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
page = page1.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
link = soup.find_all({'iframe':'src'})
link_clean = re.compile('src="(.+?)"').findall(str(z))
for item in link_clean:
    print item
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, so you are trying to get all iframes on page? Everything looks ok except you should use `src` attribute with iframes. If that doesn't help please provide an example page.

Comment: helo sir , as per your guidence i get the solution sir... i am doing mistake in between absulute / relative path... when calling them.